# CSS transition ease out not working in firefox

Tags: css

I have a simple code with grayscale svg and rollover effect to grayscale(0%).. the rollover effect works in chrome but does not work in Firefox, can you please check what could be wrong, what did I miss here ? here is my jsFiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/8yQ9K/

```
 img.grayscale:hover {
   filter: none;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
      -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
       -ms-filter: grayscale(0%); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support `filter` (or `-moz-filter`), so it's not animating [CSS Filter MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

It does support SVG `<filter>` element via `filter:url(svg-url#element-id)` which is what you're using *(you even have a comment in your code there "Firefox 3.5+")*. I'm not sure if svg filter elements are animateable in firefox, but you would want to put that in your non-grayscale svg filter where your `filter:none` is now.